# Ошибка в Обучении нейронной сети тапа данных

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>"})
Датасет одной картинки

Полный код

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
im = []
labels = ["raspberry","someduino"]
lab = []
for typ in range(2):
  for train in range(1,128):
    img = Image.open(labels[typ] + "/" + str(train) + '.jpg')
    im.append(np.array(img))
    lab.append(labels[typ])
    print("progress ", str(typ) + "." + str(train))

print(im)


train_images = im
train_labels = lab
print(train_images)
print(train_images)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(train_images[i+150], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(train_labels[i+150])

plt.show()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0,999),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)


ERROR: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e126e5caf70f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   1103     if not adapter_cls:
   1104         # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
-> 1105         raise ValueError(
   1106             "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: {}, {}".format(
   1107                 _type_name(x), _type_name(y)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), (<class 'list'> co
```

ntaining values of types {"<class 'str'>"})